# What is the best DB model for multiple answer questions

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I need to store in a DB (MSSQL) multiple answer questions, and I am having trouble deciding what is the best way to do so. Should I store questions in one table, all answers in another and right answers in a 3rd table? Should they all be in the same table?

I would love to hear your ideas

thanks

Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each concept, or entity, should be in its own table.

- Questions in a Question table
- Answers in an Answer Table with a QuestionID with a boolean field indicating its right or wrongness
  (unless Answers can belong to more than one question?)

Comment: Thanks Thats what I thougght 2. I will add another table that will connect the QuestionID and the RightAnswerID to avoid data redundancy.

Comment: That depends whether more than one answer can be chosen as correct - ie: Which of the following countries are in Europe (France, China, Belgium, Peru)

Answer (score 1):

To me in your case best way is to hold question and answer in seperate tables. If your question has multiple answer and you maybe want to use one answer in a lot of question its the best way. You should also add table for which answer is good for specific question.

In this way you don't have data redundancy in database.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with podiluska.
Each entity in a table.
If all or any of answer can be "typified" (i.e. not "free answer"), add a table for "typified answers" relating this one with table questions (to prevent someone to choose inapplicable "typified answers".
In table "user answers" relate it with table "questions" and if some record (or answer) contains a not "typified" you can mark it with a boolean column indicating "right" or "wrong".
I hope have helped you.